# detach sqlite database in java

Tags: java, sqlite, detach, sqlitejdbc

I want to detach the current sqlite database(OLD) before i attach the NEW sqlite database. But when I execute below code:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.execute("DETACH database '" + alias+"'");
statement.close();**
```

I am getting following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such database: OLD)

I have attached the database using the below code :

```
SQLiteDataSource dataSource = new SQLiteDataSource();
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.execute("ATTACH DATABASE '" + path + "' AS " + alias);
statement.close();**
```

Can anybody please help me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: if i try to execute any query for NEW and OLD databases independently they work fine and get all the required resultSet for NEW and OLD. But when i put them in same code and query them(attaching NEW database file first, querying it, then attaching the OLD and then querying OLD), i am getting duplicate data in resultSet of OLD. So i want to detach the NEW before i query OLD

Comment: Did you try it without the single quotes around the alias (as specified in the documentation)?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem
yes, i tried 1. `statement.execute("DETACH database '" + alias+"'");`
2. `statement.execute("DETACH database " + alias);`
3. `statement.execute("DETACH '" + alias+"'");`
4. `statement.execute("DETACH " + alias);`
All 4 of them gives same error :(

Comment: @user7294900 can you pls tell how to detach with PATH

Comment: Are you using the same connection object?

Comment: @CL. yes
`SQLiteDataSource dataSource = new SQLiteDataSource();
 connection = dataSource.getConnection(); `
but i am calling the method which has above code, each time i want to connect to db.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by creating new reference each time i am calling the the method for initializing database connection :)